# How to write scala jar executable by Java to fetch hostname of the machine?

Tags: java, scala, jar, scalac, javap

I want to perform this activity in Scala and execute it with Java:

```
hostname -i
```

The scala code for this is:

```
import java.net._

object HostName {
    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val localhost: InetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost
        val localIpAddress: String = localhost.getHostAddress
        println(localIpAddress)

    }
}
```

On the machine that would run the above program, there is no Scala installed. It does have Java installed though. From my understanding, Java can execute Scala code.

On my local, I perform these steps and get the answer:

```
scalac HostName.scala
scala HostName
```

I also noticed that there are two files generated:

```
HostName$.class
HostName.class
```

My objective is to run a Scala file with Java and get the result of `hostname -i` *i.e.* this code in shell. Something like this: `OUT=$(<the command to execute the script and get the result of println>)`

I have tried running the `HostName` with `javap` but it does not give the correct result:

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/random_mde/package/RandomJDK11/current/Contents/Home/bin/javap HostName
```

Result is:

```
ab-mbp-parvals
```

instead of the IP address that comes from Scala code: `a.b.c.d`.
If I run `hostname` and not `hostname -i`, I get `ab-mbp-parvals`. If I run `hostname -i` on linux machine, I get the IP.

How do I execute a scala code to perform the job of `hostname -i` without installing `hostname` on a machine that only has Java?
I am happy to `jar` my code on a machine that has Scala installed.

Comment: Write it in plain java instead.

Comment: `hostname` doesn't have to be installed, it's present by default.

Comment: Also Scala compiles to JVM bytecode, as you said no need to have scala installed on the machine to run scala code.

Comment: Agree with @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it will be faster to write it in Java, what is the purpose to have it in Scala on your machine?